# How to execute a stored Procedure in a webApi using EntityFramework with a single input parameter

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I have made a Sp with a single input parameter. I am trying to bind it with my webservice. But i am not sure how to call it inside my service and how to pass the input parameter. here is my sp

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StudentDetailss

@routeId varchar

AS

SELECT  dbo.Users.FirstName, dbo.Users.LastName, dbo.PSS_Grades.GradeNo, dbo.PSS_Divisions.Name AS DivisionName, dbo.PSS_Stops.StopName, 
        dbo.PSS_ContactDeatils.Mobile, dbo.PSS_Routes.RouteId, dbo.PSS_Routes.RouteName, dbo.PSS_Students.StudentID, dbo.PSS_RelationShips.RelationshipID, 
        MIN(dbo.PSS_RelationShips.RelationTypeID) AS RelationTypeID, Users_1.FirstName AS ParentFname, Users_1.LastName AS ParentLname

FROM    dbo.Users AS Users_1 INNER JOIN
        dbo.PSS_ContactDeatils ON Users_1.UserID = dbo.PSS_ContactDeatils.UserID INNER JOIN
        dbo.PSS_RelationShips INNER JOIN
        dbo.Users ON dbo.PSS_RelationShips.StudentUserID = dbo.Users.UserID INNER JOIN
        dbo.PSS_Routes INNER JOIN
        dbo.PSS_Students INNER JOIN
        dbo.PSS_Stops ON dbo.PSS_Students.StopId = dbo.PSS_Stops.StopId ON dbo.PSS_Routes.RouteId = dbo.PSS_Stops.RouteId ON dbo.Users.UserID = dbo.PSS_Students.StudentID AND 
        dbo.PSS_RelationShips.StudentUserID = dbo.PSS_Students.StudentID ON Users_1.UserID = dbo.PSS_RelationShips.RelatedUserID INNER JOIN
        dbo.PSS_Grades INNER JOIN
        dbo.PSS_StudentDivisions ON dbo.PSS_Grades.GradeID = dbo.PSS_StudentDivisions.GradeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.PSS_Divisions ON dbo.PSS_Grades.GradeID = dbo.PSS_Divisions.GradeID AND dbo.PSS_StudentDivisions.DivisionID = dbo.PSS_Divisions.DivisionID ON 
        dbo.PSS_Students.StudentID = dbo.PSS_StudentDivisions.StudentUserID

WHERE   PSS_Routes.RouteId=@routeId

GROUP BY    dbo.Users.FirstName, dbo.Users.LastName, dbo.PSS_Grades.GradeNo, dbo.PSS_Divisions.Name, dbo.PSS_Stops.StopName, dbo.PSS_ContactDeatils.Mobile, 
            dbo.PSS_Routes.RouteId, dbo.PSS_Routes.RouteName, dbo.PSS_Students.StudentID, dbo.PSS_RelationShips.RelationshipID, Users_1.FirstName, Users_1.LastName

HAVING  (MIN(dbo.PSS_RelationShips.RelationTypeID) <> 3)
```

I have done  Function Import and created a complex Type out of this SP. Now i want to call it inside my Api. How can it be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You have imported Your function it will be accesible via context object, like below:

```
public IEnumerable<StudentDetailss_result> GetStudentDetails(string routeId)
{
    using(var ctx = new YourContextHere())
    {
        var result = ctx.StudentDetailss(routeId);
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of this function  GetStudentDetails(string routeId) , I am getting             CreateStudentDetailsByRoute(...) with a whole list of my output parameters as input..I dont have an Idead why this happens